Way to run bash script before predeployment hook with agentless server in azure devops
I am creating deployment yaml script in azure devops.
I have a requirement to use a manual validation task to confirm such changes. But before that, we have to set variable to one of our flags as conditions to run the said manual validation task.
Here is the code now:
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        preDeploy:        
          pool: server       
          steps:
          - script: |
                if [[ "$(clusterTags)" == *"HOTFIX"* ]]; then
                  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=hotfix]true"
                else
                  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=hotfix]false"
                fi
            name: SetHotfixVariable

          - task: ManualValidation@0
            timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
            condition: eq(variables.hotfix, true)
            inputs:
              notifyUsers: ''
              instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
              onTimeout: 'resume'
        deploy:
           #usual deployment script here

I tried this approach but encountered error as I have a shell script within an agentless job. 'SIT' is a server job, but contains task 'CmdLine' which can only run on agents.
Is it possible to set these variables before the manual validation task? The cluster tag came from Pull Request Tags from azure repository.
Thank you very mych

You don't need to create an output variable named hotfix.
Instead, check the value of pipeline variable clusterTags directly in the job condition.
Example
The following sample pipeline uses the function contains in a condition to check if variable clusterTags contains string HOTFIX:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - name: clusterTags
    value: 'fooHOTFIXbar' # <---------- change value to test the condition

jobs:
  - job: waitForValidation
    displayName: Wait for external validation
    pool: server
    timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
    condition: contains(variables['clusterTags'], 'HOTFIX') # <-------- set job condition here
    steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: ''
        instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
        onTimeout: 'resume'

  - job: doSomething
    displayName: Do something
    dependsOn: waitForValidation
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - script: echo "Hello, world!"


Hi, we are encountering difficulties in accessing the output for the manual validation if accepted or rejected.
the manual validation came from pre deploy lifecycle hook while the checking of decision is on the deploy hook under condition.

The deploy hook won't be executed if the manual validation is rejected, isn't that what you need? You can as an alternative use a regular job that depends on the Manual Validation, as per my example.

I am afraid that it is not possible to run scripts in Server jobs (Agentless jobs), no such tasks available for Server jobs to run scripts.
You need to split the script task from the server job and add it to an agent job. Set the the server job depends on the agent job so that the agent job can run before the server job.
On the script task, use the setvariable command to set the variable as an output variable so that it can be passed between jobs.
stages:
- stage: deploy
  jobs:
  - job: setVar
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - task: Bash@3
      name: SetHotfixVariable
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          if [[ "$(clusterTags)" == *"HOTFIX"* ]]; then
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=hotfix;isoutput=true]true"
          else
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=hotfix;isoutput=true]false"
          fi
  
  - deployment: deploy
    dependsOn: setVar
    variables:
      hotfix: $[ dependencies.setVar.outputs['SetHotfixVariable.hotfix'] ]
    environment: myEnv
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        preDeploy:
          pool: server
          steps:
          - task: ManualValidation@0
            condition: eq(variables.hotfix, 'true')
            timeoutInMinutes: 1440
            inputs:
              notifyUsers: |
                user1@example.com
                user2@example.com
              instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume.'
              onTimeout: resume
        deploy:
          . . .


